# How do I concatenate a Control name with a value inside another variable?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

The question is it. I have some textboxes, from 0 to 10 (Example: txt0, txt1, txt2...), and I want to use a "for" instruction to refer to each text box... I was trying this:

```
Dim Value As Double
Value = CInt(txt10.Text)
Value -= CInt(txt0.Text)
Value /= 10

For i As Integer = 1 To 9 '(Here I just want to refer from the txt1 to txt9)
   (txt & i).text = Value * i + CInt(txt0.Text)
Next
```

Right now I have this repeated code instead of for:

```
txt1.Text = Value * 1 + CInt(txt0.Text)
txt2.Text = Value * 2 + CInt(txt0.Text)
txt3.Text = Value * 3 + CInt(txt0.Text)
txt4.Text = Value * 4 + CInt(txt0.Text)
txt5.Text = Value * 5 + CInt(txt0.Text)
txt6.Text = Value * 6 + CInt(txt0.Text)
txt7.Text = Value * 7 + CInt(txt0.Text)
txt8.Text = Value * 8 + CInt(txt0.Text)
txt9.Text = Value * 9 + CInt(txt0.Text)
```

Comment: TextBoxes that belong to which GUI Platform? If it's WinForms, then `[Parent].Controls("txt" & i).Text` -- You should build a class object that gets a `Value` coming `txt0` and performs operations on it, setting its Properties. Bind this class object's Properties to the other TextBoxes.

Comment: Yes, it is WinForms, and it worked! In the Parent, I used Me, and you think it's worth to build a class object like you said? Because this is just an exercise from my school. Thanks again!

Comment: Not at all, I still don't know if I really need to build a class, this is just a small UC.

Comment: The *Does this answer your question?* automatic comment appears when, after an edit, the question is marked as duplicate. -- Since it's an *exercise from my school*, I cannot tell you what you *should do*, because what you *can do* is determined by the assignment and you haven't mentioned any constraint. You should have read what's in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). -- *Yes, it is WinForms, and it worked!* clearly makes a duplicate of that Q&A (and many others).